# resources to learn developing games with ndk+opengl in C++?

Tags: android, c++, opengl-es, android-ndk

i want to learn developing games with NDK+OpenGL .
is it possible to write an android game only in C++ .

i was able to run the native-activity sample in NDK sample folder .(which is written in C) .

i was able to set up C++ support in Android.mk and Application.mk ( stl,exceptions,...) 
with the help of online NDK documentation .

native-activity sample do not have any Java code . Can i assume that it is possible to write a game without Java (only in c++) .

What are the resources ? which links and tutorials do you recommend ?
should i learn those `jni` stuff too ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes! It is possible to write a game completely in C++ and OGLES.

This material should address what you are looking for:

- [Android NDK Game Development Cookbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1782167781)
- [Beginning Android C++ Game Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430258306)